# Db persistance for dynamic collection in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

When symfony collection fields are dynamicly added/removed in DOM with javascript, on save of this collection either validation or persisted collection elem ids get messed up. For example if I have Entity\User.php releation like:

```
/**
 * @var \TestBundle\Entity\UserFollowers
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestBundle\Entity\UserFollowers", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $user_followers;
```

and backward Entity\UserFollower.php relation like:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="user_followers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

/**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;
```

And UserFormType like:

```
$builder->add('user_followers', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => UserFollowersType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'prototype_name' => '__name__',
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => 'User followers'
                ))
```

and UserFollowersFormType like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                    'attr'=> [
                        'class' =>'input input-group-field'
                    ],
                    'label' => false
                ));
    }
```

when form is handled and user persisted to db either form validation attaches to wrong collection elem or persisted id to db gets wrong, different DOM manipulaiton gets different error, controller is like:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
   $em->persist($user);
   $em->flush();
}
```

Why is that happening? its like form collection indexes gets messed up....

Comment: Likely something is messed up "When symfony collection fields are dynamicly added/removed in DOM with javascript". You need to verify what is being submitted in the HTTP request.

Comment: Javascript and DOM manipulation is good, when submiting it is for example like:
`<div id="user_form_user_followers_1">
<div id="user_form_user_followers_3">
<div id="user_form_user_followers_7">
<div id="user_form_user_followers_10">` 
but backend viewData-> collection-> elements is not indexed like (1,3,7,10)

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamicly add new UserFollowersType form you also have to replace `prototype_name`  `__name__`     with length of the collection.
On collection init:

```
var $collection = $(your collection container of forms );
$collection.data('index', $collection.children().length);
var index = $collection.data('index');
//-------on add new form 
// Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(prototypeName, index);

// increase the index with one for the next item
$collection.data('index', index + 1);
```

Comment: I am already doing it, DOM form is builded properly but indexes of DOM collection elements and backend form viewData gets messed up